# Parse Excel data in Java effectivley

Tags: java, xml, excel, apache-poi

I'm supposed to realize a Java application that should retrieve data out of an excel spreadsheet and link it to some objects I've already created in order to apply some calculations on them, then display the result .

### About the app

==> The excel spreadsheet is a survey to measure a bank's clients satisfaction about the bank's services.
==> The application should parse the data in the spreadsheet, and do some calculations on it.
==> The result should be displayed using an interactive GUI .

### What I've done so far

I've analysed to problem and create all the objects I will need in my application.
I Actually did some search here on stackoverflow.com and think that Apache POI would be very useful.

### Where I need help

The problem is that I have no idea about what I should begin with .
Any suggestions on how to accomplish this , what tools, languages, API or design pattern I should use is more than welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree with your choice of POI.  I think Andy Khan's [JExcel](http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/) is far superior.

I'd wonder why an Excel spreadsheet and not a relational database.

This sounds like a standard layered web application.  The best advice is to break the problem into pieces:

1. Acquire the data
2. Perform the calculations
3. Write the UI to display them.

Get each piece working and tested separately, then put it aside.  Work your way through the layers, one by one.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your accurate and quick answer.   A relational database would have been great but they already have a spreadsheet so I have to deal with it ( Or maybe do you think I can convert it to a relational database ?) I totally agree with you breaking the problem into those three pieces , I only have a problem in acquiring the data , this is where I need some tip of advice ..

Comment: I'd deal with it by loading the spreadsheet into the database.

Comment: Could you please tell me why JExcel is a better choice than Apache POI .

Comment: Personal experience and subjective opinion, that's all.  I think the docs for JExcel are far superior.  The whole POI API seems badly done to me.  But it's just one man's opinion.  Stick with POI if it is working for you.

Answer (score 0):

you might already be having the apache POI library , this might help you get started on source code basis

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ReadExcelFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try {

            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Users/hussain.a/Desktop/mar_25/Tradestation_Q4 Dashboard_Week 5_1029-1104.xlsx"));
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            rowIterator.next();
            while(rowIterator.hasNext())
            {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                //For each row, iterate through each columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                while(cellIterator.hasNext())
                {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    switch(cell.getCellType()) 
                    {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                            System.out.println("boolean===>>>"+cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t");
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            System.out.println("numeric===>>>"+cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            System.out.println("String===>>>"+cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                            break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            file.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Indeed, this seems to be very helpful.  Thanks a lot